# What is the difference between window.innerWidth window.outerWidth?

Tags: javascript

I examined the `window` object in Firebug. `window.innerWidth` and `window.outerWidth` are both `1230`.

What is the difference between these two values?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From Mozilla Developer Network:

*window.outerWidth*

> window.outerWidth gets the width of the outside of the browser window.
>   It represents the width of the whole browser window including sidebar
>   (if expanded), window chrome and window resizing borders/handles.

and

*window.innerWidth*

> Width (in pixels) of the browser window viewport including, if
>   rendered, the vertical scrollbar.

This is ostensibly how they work. A test page, however, shows they are both the same no matter how I resize them in Firefox 14.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. In Chromium, they return numbers that are 8 pixels different. Doing a bit of dead reckoning, it appears the window chrome on that particular app is about 4 pixels on the left side and 4 pixels on the right side and that this difference is being correctly picked up in that browser.

Code for the test page I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>12066093</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:2000px; height: 2000px;">hi</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("window.innerWidth: " + window.innerWidth + "\nwindow.outerWidth: " + window.outerWidth);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but in every case I see both of `window.innerWidth` and `window.outerWidth` is equal !!

Comment: For posterity: `window.innerWidth` and `window.outerWidth` will differ if you have zoomed in or out. `innerWidth` will show the scaled width of the window, while `outerWidth` will not take zooming into account. Suppose you have a window that is 1000px wide unzoomed. Both `innerWidth` and `outerWidth` will evaluate to 1000. If you zoom to 150% (enlarging the screen content), the `innerWidth` will become 667 (1000 / 1.5) and `outerWidth` will stay at 1000.

Comment: also if you open your dev tools, they will differ.

Comment: @mtoor I was chasing my tail for an hour because the zoom level was accidentally set at 110%.  Not enough to notice, but enough to throw out media queries and break responsiveness.

Comment: When you have devtools open and the responsive viewport selected, `outerwidth` is the width of the responsive viewport while `innerwidth` is the width of the window including the dead area outside the responsive viewport but inside the window (observed when dev tools is docked)

Answer (score 4):

Check the Mozilla reference for [window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.innerWidth) and [window.outerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.outerWidth). If your operating system/window manager has them, window.outerWidth includes the window borders, resizing handles, and sidebars.

Try opening the bookmarks or history sidebar, then trying that again in Firebug.