# Javascript: Get the true center of a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I began using `$('body').height()` and `width()` but sometimes `height()` returns `0`.

I then started to use `$('document').height()` and `width()` but it's impacted by the window size.

I guess the problem with using `document` or `body` is that they take up the entire window space. what I would need is the second largest rectangle that contains only the contents not including the margin or padding...

For example on youtube.com, when I maximize the window, the contents of the page are aligned towards the left, and there is a large amount of blank space on the right. However, the top bar (account login and logout) stretches across the full length of the window width.

How can I reliably acquire a web page's center without being impacted by the current window size?

For websites where content aligns either to the left or right, exposing a large empty space, how can I acquire the true center?

Is there a way so that the width of the website fits completely in the window size? So when I go full screen or maximize window the contents will fit snugly? What about for sites where the content does not fit instead forcing a horizontal scroll bar to appear in the browser window?

I am using webkit/mozilla based browsers and chrome to run javascript. IE is not an issue as it will never be used. I am also using jquery.

Please let me know if what I'm asking is not clear enough and I will make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `outerHeight/Width`

```
window.outerHeight;
window.outerWidth;
```

This will take the height/width of the window, so when it resizes the values will also resize.

See this link for the difference between inner/outer [What is the difference between window.innerWidth window.outerWidth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066093/what-is-the-difference-between-window-innerwidth-window-outerwidth)

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure what you are asking.

- If you want to align a container in the center of the space available, use `margin auto;`.
- If you want to make your website compatible with smaller screen sizes, take a look at responsive design, and, related, [media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries).
- `$("body").height()` should not return `0`. Put this in your CSS:

> html, body {
>       width: 100%;
>       height: 100%; }

Comment: basically I want to get the middle of the page without including the margin or padding (empty spaces) in order to get the bullseye of the actual content....or even better somehow stretch out the content of the page to fit the width of the page (so getting rid of margin and padding?)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `window.outerHeight` and `window.outerWidth` for the "current" dimensions of the window. The center would be that number divided by 2.
However... if the content it's inside an iFrame, you should use this instead:

```
$(document).outerWidth();
$(document).outerHeight();
```

You also mention that you want to align *something* to the middle of the window. For that you could try this:

```
// let 'obj' be a variable that holds DIV
// with style="display:inline-block; position:absolute"
// this function would center an element just like "modals" do
function centerElement(obj) {
    $(obj).css({
        left: ($(document).outerWidth() - $(obj).outerWidth()) / 2,
        top: ($(document).outerHeight() - $(obj).outerHeight()) / 2
    });
}

// this will 'adjust the position' of the element
$(window).resize(function () {
    centerElement($('#my-centered-div'));
});

// this will trigger the event for the first time
$(window).resize();
```

You can see a working example with this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4xkSq/2/

There is another way using only CSS if your element has a fixed size: http://jsfiddle.net/82VZe/